# Passing Database Field ID's Run SQL Depending on the Fields Value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I'm trying to build a CMS where I can click a star icon and it will change the `art_featured` value in my database, so say if `art_featured` value is 0 and I click my star icon I want to change the value of the field from 0 to 1. I kind of have it working but I don't know how to pass the `art_featured` value, usually I would just us the `id` on my `span` but I'm already using that so I can tell which article I need to change, so how can I get the value of `art_featured` to my `SQL` statement so I can run a if and else statement and then run a certain `SQL` statement depending on the value of `art_featured`,

Thanks in advance for any help!

TABLE

```
art_id  art_title  art_company    art_featured
1       lorem 1    lorem ipsum 1  1
2       lorem 2    lorem ipsum 2  0
```

HTML/PHP

```
<section class="row">
    <?php
    $sql_categories = "SELECT art_title, art_company, art_id, art_featured FROM app_articles"; 

        if($result = query($sql_categories)){
            $list = array();

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                array_push($list, $data);
            }

            foreach($list as $i => $row){ 
            ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column two"><p><?php echo $row['art_title']; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="column two"><p><?php echo $row['art_company']; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="column one"><span id="<?php echo $row['art_id']; ?>" class="icon-small star"></span></div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "FAIL";
        }
    ?>
    </section>
```

jQuery

```
        $(".star").click(function(){

        var art_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {art_id:art_id},
        url: "ajax-feature.php",
        success: function(data){
            if(data != false) {

            } 
            else {

            }  
        }
        });

    });
```

mySQL / PHP

```
    if(isset($_POST['art_id'])) {



    $sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 1 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];

    if(query($sql_articles)) {
        echo "YES";
    }
    else {
        echo "NO";
    }
}
else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_detail = "SELECT * FROM app_articles
WHERE art_id = " . $_POST['art_id'];
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql_detail);
if(mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0) { // the art_id supplied exists

    while($sR = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {

        $art_title = $sR['art_title'];
        $art_company = $sR['art_company'];
        $art_featured = $sR['art_featured];

        // Do whatever you want with these variables

    }

} else { // the art_id supplied does not exist

}
```

It's unsafe to pass the $_POST['art_id'] directly into a SQL statement, so you should probably read up on data sanitation. But this should do.

Comment: Sorry I already have the $(document).ready( function{ }); I forgot to include that. What I need to know is how to pass a php variable from my sql results to the sql statement I'm updating my database with.